# How to customize {% bootstrap_form form %} in django?

Tags: python, django, email, verification

**There is Problem**

Hello I'm creating a project, I created a register form, but I tried to create an email authentication submit button in the form near EmailInput, but I could not find it
I'm currently using `{% bootstrap_form form%}` to render automatically in a register form

**What I want**

I would like to have the Submit Email Authentication button appear on the form near EmailInput,

When the user clicks the Send Email Authentication button, it sends an authentication email to the user's email

Then, when the user clicks the link attached to the mail, the user is informed that the confirmation has been made on the register window
and When the user clicks the sign up button, the registration is completed

**What I've tried**

I created a register form using **UserCreationForm** supported by django,
I tested using gmail smtp to send email from django. It works well

**The Code** in */django-blog/blog/settings.py*

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y$a)3faq3*h#r0g5b^cxsw^lgdxbbu&#lsqek!_0ju+d*c!ups'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # 내가 만든 앱
    'my_blog',
    #USER APP
    'users',

    # Apps created by others
    'bootstrap3',

    # Restful api Framework
    'rest_framework',
    # Social
    'social_django',
    "social_core",

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# 내 설정
LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'

# django-bootstrap3 settings
BOOTSTRAP3 = {
    'include_jquery' : True,
}

#  Heroku settings

cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    # request.is_secure()에 대해 'X-Forwarded-Proto'를 우선적으로 사용한다.
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    # 모든 호스트 헤더를 허용한다.
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['choco-blog.herokuapp.com']

    DEBUG = False

    # Static asset configuration
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )

# AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS settings
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2', # for Github authentication
    'social_core.backends.kakao.KakaoOAuth2', # for Kakaotlak authentication

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # Django 기본 유저모델
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'

# Google login
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY ='843562355161-3atsmmageh4j0758g4am6e4ncefckupf.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET ='ZVKObQDFPhTdz1GXWfaYuulq'
# Github Login
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = 'e2fc4a9cf1f213b0a10f'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = 'c4d1efe407175230a47d7fa547db0667b4f08721'

# Kakaotalk login
SOCIAL_AUTH_KAKAO_KEY = '490c43bc63dd3351e6068f6bbf4e0bfd'

# Verification Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = 'True'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('KBOARD_PASSWORD')
SERVER_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_MAIL = 'my_blog'
```

*/django-blog/user/forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """유저 가입양식 정의"""
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
     max_length=32, help_text='First name', label='이름')

    last_name = forms.CharField(widget =
    forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Last Name'}),
     max_length=32, help_text='Last name', label='성')

    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.EmailInput(attrs=
        {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email',}),
         max_length=64, help_text='유효한 이메일 주소를 입력하세요',
         error_messages={'invalid': ("Email 이 비어있습니다")},)

    terms = forms.BooleanField(
        label =('My blog of service'),
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={
                'required': 'True',
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
            'required':('당신의 My blog of service 에 대한 동의가 필요합니다. ')
        }
    )

    privacy = forms.BooleanField(
        label=('Privacy policy'),
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={
                'required':'True',
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
            'required=':('당신의 Privacy policy 동의가 필요합니다.')
            }
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('first_name',
         'last_name', 'email')
```

*/django-blog/user/urls.py*

```
"""users 앱의 URL 패턴을 정의하는 파일"""

from django.urls import re_path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # 로그인 페이지
    re_path(r'^login/$',
    auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
    name = 'login'),

    # 로그아웃 페이지
    re_path(r'^logout/$',views.logout_view, name='logout'),

    # 유저 등록 페이지
    re_path(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

*/django-blog/user/templates/user/register.html*

```
{% extends "my_blog/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>회원가입</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <form method='post' action="{% url 'users:register' %}" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    {% buttons %}
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success">유저 등록하기</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
    <input type="hidden" name="text" value="{% url 'my_blog:index' %}">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

*/django-blog/user/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import  UserCreationForm


def logout_view(request):
    """사용자 로그아웃"""
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_blog:index'))

def register(request):
    """새 사용자를 등록한다."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # 빈 폼을 보여준다.
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        # 전송받은 폼을 처리한다.
        form =UserCreationForm(data = request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            # 사용자를 로그인시키고 홈페이지로 리다이렉트한다.
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_blog:index'))

    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

**I have attached a register screen photo**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMfiv.png)

**If you need information to solve this problem, please ask me :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/). With help of this you can add classes to your input and edit other attribute also. Here is good [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html).

Comment: It's a bit cumbersome, but it has helped me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can customize it in a bootstrap field:

https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html?highlight=layout#bootstrap-field

Like this with new css w3-css

```
{% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' form_group_class='w3-input w3-border-0 w3-large'%}
```